# OpenApi Generator typescript-axios Only interfaces output with typescript axios generator

Tags: typescript, axios, openapi-generator

I started using the OpenApi Generator for TypeScript and Axios. It works really good! The only thing I'm wondering is, how can I generate classes instead of interfaces?

With e.g. typescript-node I get all models as classes with optional Interfaces when setting the option withInterfaces. With typescript-axios I only get interfaces ... This is quite annoying ... can anyone help me out?

I'm using version 1.0.12-4.3.0

Thanks in advance,
Andi

Answer (score 1):

What I do is, I have `openapi-templates` folder in the root of my project.

Then you have to find the template you want to override on [openapi-generator github](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/tree/master/modules/openapi-generator/src/main/resources/typescript-axios).

I'm not sure what exactly you're using, so this bit might be slightly different for you but.. I'm using the docker version of [openapi-generator-cli](https://hub.docker.com/r/openapitools/openapi-generator-cli/) and I'm mounting my physical folder (the one where I put the `openapi-templates` folder), as `:/local` in docker. And then I use the `-t /local/openapi-templates` command line switch to tell the generator to look into my `openapi-templates` folder for any template overrides which it should apply over the default ones.

Next, you should download the `modelGeneric.mustache` file from that github link. Put the file inside the `openapi-templates` folder, and modify it. Basically you need to change the `interface` keyword to `class` keyword.

Now run your generator with that extra command line param and you should be have generated classes instead of interfaces, and since in TS classes can act as interfaces, there are no real drawbacks.

Just keep in mind that openapi team updates these templates every once in a while, so now you might have to maintain your custom overridden files.. Perhaps check every 6 months if a new default template is out there and apply your customizations to it.